# MoonMail deploy function uglify.js errors

Tags: moonmail

After deploying the resources, I am receiving many similar errors related to `uglify.js` when trying to deploy the functions (see below for one).

It seems most likely to me that the errors are from some sort of dependency and/or version problem, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

```
Serverless: / uglify-js failed on _meta/_tmp/deliverCampaign@1484235001988/node_
modules/moonmail-models/node_modules/joi/node_modules/hoek/lib/escape.js : Synta
xError: Unexpected token: name (escaped) (line: 14, col: 8, pos: 160)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sam.d\Documents\moonmail\MoonMail-master\node_modules\serverless-runtime-babel\node_modules\minifyify\node_modules\uglifyjs\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1547:18)
```

Comment: it seems that the issue is caused by `joi`, which for us normally outputs some warnings when deploying functions, but none of them prevent the function to be deployed. Which `joi` version do you have installed under `api/node_modules`?

Comment: it is joi@8.4.2

Comment: What version do you have davids?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Mine one is `8.4.2`, and `hoek` version (the library that is crashing when you deploy) is `4.1.0`

Comment: Anybody got this issue solved ?

Comment: As davids said this errors are swallowed by `uglify-js` and seem to be related to `joi` but this should not prevent a successful deployment if you are facing issues, this is not the cause we see the same output on our everyday deployments.